# Dynamically changing session factory and Txm Manager for I18N support

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-transactions, spring-orm

I have a peculiar issue here in the Spring-GWT application we are building. We have an oracle DB encoded in WE8ISO8859P1 character set which doesn't support UTF-8 . Hence we are building a new DB in AL32UTF8 char set . Unfortunately the DBAs do not want to migrate the existing DB to the new DB and we have to reach the old DB for the English data and the new DB for the Latin data .

We have @Transactional annotations at method/class level and the sessionFactory is injected into the DAO to connect to hibernate. I want to reuse these when user selects latin something like

@Transactional(changeThisDynamically)

i.e, the TransactionManager and SessionFactory injected should change dynamically via an Ajax call when the user switches between Latin/English.

Can this be done? What is is the best approach to resolve this ?

On second thought, I could get the Latin session factory by making the bean ApplicationContextAware and set this in the dao but but is this a good approach ? and what do I do with the TransactionManager ?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you consider Hibernate Shards(http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/shards.html)?

Comment: @Adi Thanks for the tip but we are not working with Sharded Datasets . Infact, we don't dave any control over the DB architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. What I really needed was an 'AbstractRoutingDataSource' - I fixed this by doing the following

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.myPackage.CustomRoutingDataSource">
   <property name="targetDataSources">
      <map key-type="com.myPackage.DBLocaleEnum">
         <entry key="English" value-ref="defaultDataSource"/>
         <entry key="Spanish" value-ref="latinDataSource"/>
      </map>
   </property>
   <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="defaultDataSource"/>
</bean>

public class CustomRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

@Override
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {

    DBLocaleEnum localeType = LocaleContextHolder.getLocaleType();
    return localeType;
}
```

The return type of determineCurrentLookupKey method helps me determine which datasource I should be using .